# Make the a:after show when the page is active

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a navigation menu. Now I want to make my a:after show when the page is active. i can control the a when active but the after won't show.

i have this [html](http://prntscr.com/778aea) the css is.

```
.navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a > .active {
  color: #337AB7;
}
```

Here what it looks [like](http://prntscr.com/778ale). Now I want is something like [this](http://prntscr.com/778b2p) when the page is active. this only triggers when hovered on any menu.

here is the css for it.

```
.nav>li>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(9,49,113,1);
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  transform: translateY(10px);
  margin-top: -13px;
}
```

Comment: Post the HTML code here, Michael

Comment: When would you consider a page to be 'active'?

Comment: this link might be useful if you can use js http://webdesignerhut.com/active-class-navigation-menu/

Comment: @DavidThomas when Im on the page for example im on the FURTHERMORE page the effect will be visible on FURTHERMORE.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS code to center the border and reducing it's width.

```
.navbar-nav > .active > a:after 
{
  color: #337AB7;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #093171;
}
```